# When is it good for the Alphawolf to strike early in the game, and when is it good for him to wait?

Tags: werewolv.es

The H2P says, "The Alphawolf's extra kill is generally used for two reasons: early on, to thin the village out before they have a chance to unite themselves, or when multiple village roles have announced themselves and you want to kill as many of them as possible."

What are some other considerations?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, there's not much else apart from these 2 scenarios to consider an alpha strike. This, I believe, is mostly due to the fact that it's a once-per-game ability, so the pack is inclined to maximise the benefit of killing 2 village players who've claimed their roles (and are deemed dangerous to the pack).

Answer (score 1):

An Alpha's enraged kill is much like a militias single shot, often debated for best use (only got one) before they get killed off.No matter the case, it comes down to the Alpha's judgement on when to use.

Some other instances for Alpha Rage kill

1. Click happy...what this do (random player dies)
2. I don't like you for some reason....you now dead (selected personal "rival" dead)
3. hide a shift.....Two kills one real shift other to make it seem like decoy was real SS (make players look for decoy not your fellow wolf)
4. Looks like they are on to me.....I'm going to use it and take someone with me to the GY.
5. extra death makes it seem Omega still alive/ was killing wolf even if not